# How to merge a postgres table into another?

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a main `postgres` table with constraints, primary key (`id`) and the usual stuff.

Then I have a temporary table that has the same columns, but without the constrains. I use that temporary table for mass batch inserts.

From time to time I want to merge these tables `by id`, means: I want to insert the data from the temporary table into the main table, ensuring that:

- id's that don't exist in main table should just be inserts
- id's that do exists should be updates

How could these be best implemented for approx 1 million+ entries in the temporary table?

Comment: This is not an easy problem. If you search for `postgres upsert` or `on duplicate update`, you'll see that it's quite a big issue, whether done in Java or directly from psql.

Comment: Is your `id` a `serial` (i.e. owns a sequence)? If you want to keep your temporary table's `id`s **and** use the sequence for other inserts in your main table, you should lock the entire table for the insertion (you need to fix your sequence manually, after the insertion) -- upserts usually work best, if you would have another unique constraint (other than the generated primary key).

Comment: `id` is not a database sequence, and I don't want auto increments on insert, as I control the IDs externally. I want the id's from the temp table to be exactly the same after merge, as they serve as an identifier if a row is to be updated (if id exists) or newly inserted (if id not exists).

Comment: @membersound then upserts can work for you, you can find several solutions here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+upsert -- or the official solution in the docs http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING (waiting for `MERGE` https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT )

Comment: @pozs the `merge_db()` lookg promising, anyhow it expects an explicit ID for comparison. How could I wrap around this to loop through all ids from the temp table?

Comment: @membersound the official solution is the safest, but i must admit it will be the slowest too. I would recommend to build up multiple solutions, & test it with real data -- in case of `merge_db()`, you could create the function which accepts a whole row, then call it like `select merge_row(temp_table) from temp_table`

Answer (score 0):

Following answer is based on `UPDATES` made in a brutal way: `DELETE + INSERT`

1. Drop constraints on the main table

   `ALTER TABLE [main_table] DROP CONSTRAINT ...`

   `ALTER TABLE [main_table] DROP CONSTRAINT ...`
2. Delete rows from the main table that exist in the temporary one

   `DELETE FROM [main_table] WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM [temp_table]);`
3. Insert into the main table everything from the temp table

   `INSERT INTO [main_table] SELECT * FROM [temp_table];`
4. Recreate the constraints

   `ALTER TABLE [main_table] ADD FOREIGN KEY ...`

   `ALTER TABLE [main_table] ADD FOREIGN KEY ...`

Answer (score -1):

You should use `merge` statment:

```
MERGE INTO main_table main
USING temp_table temp
ON main.Id = temp.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET main.name=temp.name ....
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
 INSERT VALUES (Id, .....)
```

Comment: Unfortunately Postgres has no `MERGE` statement